# Load emacs desktop/session from current directory

Tags: emacs, desktop

I know a few questions have touched on this area and there seems to be quite convoluted solutions to getting it to work. According to the wording of the emacs manual, it clearly states that you should be able to open emacs from a certain directory and the emacs.desktop file in that directory should be used when the program is opened.

However, this is not the case, and even if I cd into the correct directory and type 'emacs', it only opens the desktop file in ~/.emacs_d/. I then have to use M-x desktop-change-dir and then my current directory (.).

Is the manual using confusing wording, or if I want to have multiple desktop files spread across different directories, opening the one corresponding to the directory I open emacs from, will I have to use other methods and edit the init file further? (using emacs25)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the need really to open the desktop file that is in the current directory? Do you know that you can store any number of desktop files anywhere? You do not need to have only one per directory. You can also bookmark desktops (using [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks)). Then it is trivial to open any of them (just "jump" to the corresponding desktop bookmark). Where the desktop files are stored is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah great, how does that work with regard to actually naming each file, as aren't the desktop files stored with the same name? I may have saw something similar to that called Desktop+, of which I will use either of the two in the end I imagine. I was just wondering why when I open emacs from a certain directory it does not detect the one desktop file stored in the same directory, only from the default location? Thanks.

Comment: When you create a desktop bookmark you are prompted for the desktop-file location (i.e., name and directory) and the bookmark name. See the doc for command `bmkp-set-desktop-bookmark`.

Answer (score 4):

Not totally sure it fits you needs, but it works for me. I prefer several .emacs.desktop, each sits in own directory. To support this, I added to .emacs

```
(setq desktop-path '("."))
```

and run emacs from a directory with .emacs.desktop.

Comment: upvoted! I do the same technique that you do.
see also: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DesktopMultipleSaveFiles

Comment: This works perfectly and makes `desktop-save-mode` work the way it's described in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions). The problem is that the default for desktop-path is `("~/emacs.d", "~")` which means it will never look in the CWD for your `.emacs.desktop` file, which is contrary to the linked doc.